# Using the ternary operator inside "for"

Tags: c, for-loop, ternary

i'm a beginner in programming.
the code does get compiled but prints out values not understandable.
when i put those values inside the outer "for" by declaring extra integers, and put them into use, the code seems to properly work. What is the problem with the code below? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    int num1, num2, i, j, k;
    printf( "Enter the two Integers: " );
    scanf( "%d%d", &num1, &num2 );
    for ( i = (num1 < num2) ? num1 : num2; i <= (num1 > num2) ?num1 : num2; ; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 1; j <= 9; j++ ) {
            printf( "%d x %d = %-2d", i, j, i*j );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Did you make a typo? There are two consecutive `;` in your first for loop.

Comment: The code you posted in your question does not compile because of the doubled `;` in the `for` statement. This also tells us you did not paste exactly the code you are using, so we have to wonder whether there may be other errors. You should edit your question to show **exactly** the code that fails. You should also show the code that works, and you should show exactly the input you give it that results in incorrect output.

Comment: (1) Present the code you are actually asking about.  Preferrably,  copy & paste it into the question.  What you have presented does not compile.  (2) Present the expected and actual output you get.

Comment: Why are you even trying to stuff all that code into the `for()` statement in the first place?  Unless you're [competing in the IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/) there's no reason to do that.

Comment: To Adrew: Yes I do know that such codes are awkward but I was just experimenting by giving trivial changes and that's how I got into this problem :) Besides, for a beginner, IOCCC is a quite unreachable goal :3

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with operator precedence.  The ternary operator has very low precedence, higher only than the assignment operator, compound assignment operators, and comma operator.  Thus, your loop condition

```
i<=(num1>num2)?num1:num2
```

is equivalent to

```
(i<=(num1>num2))?num1:num2
```

.  That expression will always evaluate to the value of either `num1` or `num2`, so unless one of those is zero, your loop will never terminate.  This also explains why you observed different behavior when you precomputed the ternary expressions.

You want this:

```
for(i = ((num1 < num2) ? num1 : num2);
        i <= ((num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2); i++) {
```

But actually, I'd recommend the precomputation in the first place.  The code is slightly longer, but much clearer.

Comment: Thank you for a brief and clear answer! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is a typo in the for statement

```
for(i=(num1<num2)?num1:num2;i<=(num1>num2)?num1:num2;; i++)
                                                   ^^^^
```

There is a redundant semicolon.

According to the C Standard the conditional operator is defined the following way

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

Relative to this expression

```
i<=(num1>num2)?num1:num2
```

then it is interpreted like

```
( i<=(num1>num2) ) ? num1 : num2
```

It is evident that you mean instead

```
i <= (num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2 )
```

Nevertheless it would be better to use one if statement before the loops than using the conditional operators in the loop.

Take into account that in any case the first loop is unsafe because the user can enter a value equal to `INT_MAX`. In this case the program will have undefined behavior. It is better and safe to use `do-while` loop.

Also for the result of multiplication it is better to use the type `long long int`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    printf( "Enter two Integers: " );

    scanf( "%d%d", &num1, &num2 );

    if ( num2 < num1 )
    {
        int tmp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = tmp;
    }

    int i = num1;
    do
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j < 10; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d x %d = %-2lld\n", i, j, ( long long int )i * j );
        }
        printf("\n");
    } while ( i++ != num2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter two Integers: 1 5
1 x 1 = 1 
1 x 2 = 2 
1 x 3 = 3 
1 x 4 = 4 
1 x 5 = 5 
1 x 6 = 6 
1 x 7 = 7 
1 x 8 = 8 
1 x 9 = 9 

2 x 1 = 2 
2 x 2 = 4 
2 x 3 = 6 
2 x 4 = 8 
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18

3 x 1 = 3 
3 x 2 = 6 
3 x 3 = 9 
3 x 4 = 12
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
3 x 8 = 24
3 x 9 = 27

4 x 1 = 4 
4 x 2 = 8 
4 x 3 = 12
4 x 4 = 16
4 x 5 = 20
4 x 6 = 24
4 x 7 = 28
4 x 8 = 32
4 x 9 = 36

5 x 1 = 5 
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
```

Answer (score 1):

Your weird results are due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the ternary operator is executed after comparing i with (num1>num2). So when you write

```
i<=(num1>num2)?num1:num2;
```

You're actually writing something like

```
(i<=(num1>num2))?num1:num2;
```

So the condition relies on the value of num1 or num2. Just add parenthesis around your ternary operator and you're good.

Comment: Better yet, don't write code that you have to stare at for three minutes to figure out.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That is bad advice for students. It is important, even necessary, that students explore and experiment, and even code that is simple to experienced programmers will take considerable time for a student to figure out.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, although I agree that there is didactic value in *interpreting* complex code, and also that "complex" is a relative measure, I heartily agree with what I take as Andrew's sentiment: that one should generally prefer to write simpler code for any given task over more complex code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you really saying students should *write* code that's hard to understand?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I am saying students should experiment. That will inevitably cause them to write code that is hard to understand. That is not the purpose of it, of course, but it is an inevitable consequence. At the point in learning where a student is figuring out how expressions are interpreted, the advice not to write complicated code is useless; they do not even know what the alternatives are. It is like giving a baby who is just learning to walk advice on how to do an elegant curtsy or bow.

Comment: Optimizing a little, because num1 and num2 don't change after being set by the user, both result of both ternary operator should be stored in constants so they are not processed on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In `i<=(num1>num2)?num1:num2`, `<=` has higher precedence than `? :`. So this expression is equivalent to:

```
(i <= (num1 > num2))  ?  num1  :  num2;
```

Thus, the expression always evaluates to one of `num1` or `num2`. If they are both non-zero, then the loop continues forever.

What you actually want is:

```
i <= (num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2)
```

Answer (score -2):

The etrtra `;` is the problem. It means do nothing. The i++ as the 4th statement is ignored.

Anyway, complex expressions inside the for statement make code more difficult to read (by humans) same times with the negative performance effect.

Comment: The extra `;` would prevent compilation. It would not cause the program to “[print] out values not understandable” as the question reports. So it is not the cause of the problem. The OP must have posted code different from the code causing the problem, and that needs to be clarified before an answer can be provided.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time posting the question, and I consequently made a terrible mistake! 'I'll be more aware of properly posting the code. Sorry.